# moving data in the network stream

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, spoken-english

My English teacher said that it isn't correct to say:
"current of data"
Is he right?
so how can I say a moving data from one hardware(e.i. computer, memory) to other?

---

I think about:

"stream of data". Is it right?

What is the problem in first use?

Comment: If you use the noun, current, you can use it as data current.

Comment: *Current* is the movement of water within a body of water. A *stream* is a body of water. The metaphor is not the same. *Data stream* is a common term for any sequence of data that is produced by one component and consumed by another. Another is *pipeline*. *Data current* and *current of data* are not used.

Comment: @epl That's only one sense of *current*. It could also be the metaphorical equivalent of an electrical current—flowing data that conveys information, rather than flowing electricity that conveys power.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Of course, it could mean such, in principle, but it does not do so, in practice. The metaphors normally used are that between a flowing body of water and some transfer of data, and that between water currents and a specific class of electrical activity. Inferring from these particular metaphors a completely separate one has no value. Are any sources available suggesting that *data current* is in active use at any level near that of *data stream*?

Comment: @epl That's immediately what I thought of when I heard *data current*: electricity, not water. And metaphors are not real. They exist in the mind of each person who hears them—even if they aren't common expressions, which this one is not. You cannot say that the interpretation is wrong or that the expression itself is wrong (has no value). All you can say is that the expression itself is uncommon.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I have determined nothing to be wrong, only that the metaphor in question is uncommon, perhaps virtually unknown, in current usage. Such observation carries the implication that someone may wish to restrict its use, for example, to creative literature, instead of invoking it in a technical document, which may be the most unsurprising context for a reference to the subject matter. If some question would be given as general as to seek permission to create some metaphor that others may understand when explained to them, then no discussion is required.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particularly wrong with using the word "current" as a metaphor for the flow of data from one place to another, it's just not commonly used in this context and it's likely that the listener won't understand what you mean.

[Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)), on the other hand, has a well-defined meaning in computing and is a more commonly used metaphor.